# unable to get the source page of Session value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I know it's a question that everybody shall think to be silly. But i researched on net a lot but not getting it.
I am not able to get the source page of session value. Only I can see the source as  in the current web application as below. We are also using web services and wcf services to communicate with other applications. what more could i find to get the session source page where its value is being set.

```
public SessionData CurrentSession
        {
            get { return Session["xyz"] as SessionData; }
            set { Session["xyz"] = value; }
        }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to find where the Session is being set. Have you tried just search with that session name?

Comment: @wctiger : yes , i tried, it has been used at many places but unable to get the source of it or from which application it's value is coming from.

Comment: You've done a "Find All References" on `CurrentSession` ?